# creating an email template for Gmail - issues with media queries

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, gmail

I am trying to create an email template with HTML + CSS for GMAIL. It will be responsive!
But I know that "media queries" are not supported by gmail. So I am trying to create a "fluid layout" using old-fashioned HTML tags (table, td etc) and percentage instead of using CSS tags. I've already created a template (like here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978) but still have a problem;

When I resize the browser I want -left column- to move at the bottom but now -right column- moves there. 
How can I code so that left column will be at the bottom and the right one will be on the top of it. Is it possible to do it without using the "media queries" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is can be caused by your tables being in the wrong order. Make sure the table with -left col- inside is placed underneath the -right col-. So long as the table wrapper is aligned to the left, it will still appear that way when viewed.

If that answer doesn't help, can you please provide a snippet of your HTML and I can take a look at what is causing the issue?